# why android_log_print abnormal when using 1e-3?

Tags: android, c++, printf

```
int test1 = 111111111;
int test2 = 222222222;
int test3 = 333333333;
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "mingxuanli0", " test1 = %d ms test2 = %d ms", (test1 * (1e-3)), test2);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "mingxuanli1", " test1 = %d ms test2 = %d ms", (test1 * (1e-3)), test2, test3);`

mingxuanli0:  test1 = 222222222 ms test2 = 0 ms
mingxuanli1:  test1 = 222222222 ms test2 = 333333333 ms
```

[image]

[image]

it is correct when don‘t use 1e-3

Comment: mingxuanli0:  test1 = 222222222 ms test2 = 0 ms
mingxuanli1:  test1 = 222222222 ms test2 = 333333333 ms

Comment: I do not see it as a typo. It looks more like an important misunderstanding of literals and their types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1e-3` (and anything else with exponent) is a [`double` literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal). Thus, the result of `test1 * (1e-3)` is a `double` by the [implicit conversion rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions).

Using `%d` you tell [`__android_log_print`](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/logging#group___logging_1gac60e52c9711c53803ad9af639083afd5) that you are going to provide an `int`, but then you provide a `double`. That's Undefined Behaviour.

You probably want to do simply `test1 / 1000`, without getting into floating point territory. If you do want floats, use `%f` as specifier instead of `%d`.